# DropDownList inside the for loop in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I am kind lost with the DropDownList inside the for loop in ASP.net View. Here is what I am trying do. I have Class called OrganizationAddress which has object Organization, Address

```
  public class OrganizationAddress
{

public OrganizationAddress ()
    {
        this.address = new List<Address>();
    }

    public Organization organization { get; set; }

    public List<Address> address { get; set; }

}
public partial class Address
    {

    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int AddressTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Provience { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
OrganizationAddress organizationadd = new OrganizationAddress ();
ViewBag.AddressTypeID = new    SelectList(db.AddressTypes,"AddressTypeID","Name");
return View(organizationadd);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( FormCollection f, List<Address> address)
{
OrganizationAddress organizationadd = new OrganizationAddress ();
ViewBag.AddressTypeID = new   SelectList(db.AddressTypes,"AddressTypeID","Name");
return View(organizationadd);
}
```

View

```
@model panther.Models.OrganizationAddress 
for (int i = 0; i < Model.address.Count(); i++)
{
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.address[i].AddressTypeID, "AddressTypeID",    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.DropDownList("AddressTypeID",new SelectList("[" + i +  "].AddressTypeID", "AddressTypeID", "Name"))
</div>
</div>
}
```

I am getting "DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'AddressTypeID'.". Can you guys help me to find out the mistake I am doing here. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery for adding new address field?

Comment: I am not to sure how it's done with jQuery. I would really appreciate if any examples how it can be achieved.